# OOP in Python , Getting Truth Table using Tree model

Tags: python-3.x, oop, recursion, tree

So I am given a task to use OOP to get the following truth table. I have to make method make_tt() on an expression i.e.

```
e=Eq(NOT(Var('y')),Var('x'))
```

such that it returns the following truth table.

where, Eq represent '==' and NOT represent '!'

```
   y | x    | !y==x
True | True | False
False| True | True
True | False| True
False| False| False
```

I have first made parent class Expr from which I will make Eq and Not class to inherit common things but I don't know how to write make_tt() such that it produces the following results.

```
class Expr:
  def __init__ (self,left,right):
    self.left=left
    self.right=right

  def __str__(self):
    return f'{self.left}{self.sign}{self.right}'

class Not(Expr):
  def __init__(self,variable):
    self.variable=variable

  sign='!'

  def __str__(self):
    return f'{self.sign}{self.variable}'

class Eq(Expr):
  sign='=='

class Var:
  def __init__(self,value):
    self.value=value

  def __str__(self):
    return str(self.value)

e=Eq(NOT(Var('y')),Var('x'))
```

if i do this

```
e.make_tt()
```

It should produce the truth table as you have seen above.

```
   y | x    | !y==x
True | True | False
False| True | True
True | False| True
False| False| False
```

Answer (score 1):

Truth tables need to cover every combination of values the inputs can be. Using binary values, each variable has two states: True/False. This means that for every variable in the table, your number of combinations will multiply by two.

Ex:

```
vars a,b,c   -> 2*2*2   =  8 total combinations
vars a,b,c,d -> 2*2*2*2 = 16 total combinations
```

This is why, given your variables y/x, you need a table with 4 rows + the header. (y,x -> 2*2 = 4 total) The end column is just the result you get when you plug your variables at some value into the equation which in this case is (not y == x).

What you need to do is populate a list or dict or some other data container with the possible combinations first. You then iterate over that sequence of combinations and pass each into your equation which should return its truth value. If you log the return from the expression along with the combination you used, you will essentially have created your truth table and will then just need to print it to the console.

An example of a way to contain your combinations would be to use a list of tuples like so:

`combinations = [(1,1), (0,1), (1,0), (0,0)]`  (1 means True, 0 means False)

You can then get the variables by just assigning a tuple to two vars like so:

`y,x = combinations[1]` which results in `y=0, x=1` since it got the second combination in the list. If you were to plug that into the equation youd get: `not y == x` --> `not 0 == 1` --> `1 == 1` --> `True` so for the combination `(False,True)` the result is `True`

That should get you started. Id reccomend playing around in python and testing different ways to use this to build your table.